# What is error: "Base table or view not found: 1146"

Tags: entities, database

Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '(database).(entity)__(field_name)' doesn't exist

I have problems running my site since i deleted field (field_name) from entity (entity), to be clear entity was created from ContentEntityType.

**What kind of field is it, if it has it's own table and those two underscores in table name?**

**How can i create field of this kind to solve this error?**

It is quite urgent and my bad is i don't have any database backups.

Comment: How did you delete the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the fix!!! (Yes, i am user96758)

After 3 hours of investigation, internet and uncle Google wasn't helpfull at all.

The problem was that field was created via Drupal UI in Content Type -> Manage fields.
And it was deleted programatically by using UPDATE (code example below), not by using UI.

```
function hook_update_N(&$sandbox){
    $update_manager = Drupal::service('entity.definition_update_manager');
    $definition = $update_manager->getFieldStorageDefinition('field_name', 'entity_id');
    $update_manager->uninstallFieldStorageDefinition($definition);
    return t('Entity: field was uninstalled');
}
```

I have installed module named "Devel", which is pretty good damn module and every developer should have it.

I was finding **anything** that contains name of my problematic field.

Thanks to Devel module i was able to find config of this field.
Usually you can see all configs at url **(your_site)/devel/config**

Well, i was desperate, so the last chance was to delete the config i found.
Usually the fields are named: **field.field.(entity).(entity).(field_name)**

I removed the config with this code below

```
Drupal::configFactory()
    ->getEditable('field.field.(entity).(entity).(field_name)')
    ->delete();
```

Then i **CLEARED CACHE** and **IT WORKS AGAIN**!

Comment: So, if i can ask someone to set this question as "Solved". Thanks again :)

Comment: To mark the question as solved, log in as user96758 and accept your answer.